# Does Gaussian Naive Bayes have paramter to be tuned

Tags: machine-learning, probability, naive-bayes, hyperparameter

I am trying to implement the Gaussian Naive Bayes from a scikit-learn library. I know that the Naive Bayes is based on the Bayes' theorem which is defined in high level as:
`posterior = (prior * likelihood) / evidence.`

As far as I know, the prior and evidence are learned from the training data.

I am not sure about likelihood whether Q1: is it also learned from the training data or by using *Maximum likelihood estimation* ?.
Q2: Is there any hyper-parameter required to be tuned or not ?.

Comment: For the future, please keep in mind that [cross-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213118/does-gaussian-naive-bayes-have-paramter-to-be-tuned) verbatim questions at more than one SE sites is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the library [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#naive-bayes)  :

[GaussianNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) implements the Gaussian Naive Bayes algorithm for classification. **The likelihood of the features is assumed to be Gaussian. The parameters (sigma, mu) are estimated using maximum likelihood.** The likelihood function of gaussian distribution, where Xs are your features and the parameters (mu, sigma) are parameters of the normal distribution, since the model assumption is that **your data** is taken from a normal distribution (that is why it is a gaussian naive Bayes )

$P(x_i \mid y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_y}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu_y)^2}{2\sigma^2_y}\right)$

Regarding the hyperparameters, the implementation of GaussianNB let you add var_smoothing , Which is the portion of the largest variance of all features that is added to variances for calculation stability. You do not have to use it.